# Is there a way to retrieve an episode count & dates from an actor that played multiple roles?

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

To be clearer : I would like to retrieve in how many episodes *of a serie* an actor appeared (with the dates) as it's displayed in IMDB.

[I'm using the Doctor Who page as an example](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0436992/)

[image: Cast for Doctor Who]

In this case, I would like to know that Matt Smith appeared in 46 episodes, from 2010 to 2020.

IMDB does perfectly that on a character object, with currentRole, and it's notes attribute

```py
from imdb import IMDb

ia = IMDb()
movie = ia.get_movie('0436992') # id for Doctor Who
cast = movie['cast']
print("Actor name :", cast[0]['name'])
print("Role :", cast[0].currentRole)
print("Notes :", cast[0].notes)
```

Displays

```
Actor name : Matt Smith
Role : The Doctor
Notes : (58 episodes, 2010-2020)
```

*(weirdly, the episode count is wrong, as there is 46 written on the website, and 54 episodes shown if you click on it, but this is not my point)*

However, other actors played multiple characters in this serie, `Character.currentRole` returns then a list. I changed my code to get it correctly :

```py
from imdb import IMDb

ia = IMDb()
movie = ia.get_movie('0436992')
cast = movie['cast']

for i in range(2):

    print("Actor name :", cast[i]['name'])

    if isinstance(cast[i].currentRole, list):
        print("Roles :")
        for role in cast[i].currentRole:
            print(" - ", role, " (Note :" + role.notes + ")")

    else:
        print("Role :", cast[i].currentRole)
    print("Notes :", cast[i].notes)
    print("")
```

But the result is :

```
Actor name : Matt Smith
Role : The Doctor
Notes : (58 episodes, 2010-2020)

Actor name : David Tennant
Roles :
 -  The Doctor  (Note :)
 -  ...  (Note :)
Notes :
```

I can't retrieve informations I would like here, and all of the "notes" are empty. I tried digging up in the Person and Character objects from imdbpy while debugging, couldn't find what I need.

It seems that it occurs only for actors playing multiple characters, is there a way to retrieve this with imdbpy, and not an external parser ?

Any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem. Sadly I was not able to solve it with IMDbPY as well. I think it is buggy.
Instead I wrote my own parser with bs4:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# parse the page with bs4
page = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0436992/fullcredits')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

# find the cast table
table = soup.find('table', {"class": "cast_list"})

cast = []

# iterate over it
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    column_marker = 0
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    cast_member = {}
    for column in columns:
        # name column
        if column_marker == 1:
            cast_member['name'] = column.get_text().strip()
        # combined role and episodes/years column
        elif column_marker == 3:
            links = column.find_all('a')
            role_element = column.find('a', {'class': None})
            if role_element:
                cast_member['role'] = role_element.get_text().strip()
            episodes_and_years_element = column.find('a', {'class': 'toggle-episodes'})
            if episodes_and_years_element:
                episodes_and_years = episodes_and_years_element.get_text().strip().split(', ')
                cast_member['episodes'] = episodes_and_years[0]
                if len(episodes_and_years) > 1:
                    cast_member['years'] = episodes_and_years[1]
        column_marker += 1
    if len(cast_member):
        cast.append(cast_member)

print(cast[:5])
```

It is definitely not the most elegant solution, but I believe it does what you want.

Comment: Yes, it is bugged. We investigated with a friend the imdbpy repository; it is based on an old IMDB version, and the parsing isn't well done, there's no better solution than parsing yourself or PR-ing a fix to the repository